# Archive (copy contents only) certain sheets in a Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have an archiver I am using from another project, to make an archived copy of the contents of a spreadsheet, sheet by sheet. My problem is, that archiver was used to get all of the sheets of the spreadsheet for the other project. For this project, I only want certain sheets to be in the array of sheets (not all of them). How can I modify this function to do that? I've tried a few approaches but they always screw up the map function. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
function Archive() {
   var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi(); // Same variations.

  var result = ui.prompt(
      'What would you like to call this file?',
      'Please enter file name:',
      ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

  // Process the user's response.
  var button = result.getSelectedButton();
  var text = result.getResponseText();
  if (button == ui.Button.OK) {
    // User clicked "OK".
  var spreadsheetId = "Spreadsheet ID"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID.
  var destFolderId = "Target Folder ID";  // Please set the destination folder ID.

  // Copy each sheet in the source Spreadsheet by removing the formulas as the temporal sheets.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var arraysheets = ["Budget Input","Budget (Universal)","Covid Parameters"]
  var tempSheets = ss.getSheets().map(function(sheet) {
    var dstSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheet.getSheetName() + "_temp");
    var src = dstSheet.getDataRange();
    src.copyTo(src, {contentsOnly: true});
    return dstSheet;
  });

  // Copy the source Spreadsheet.
  var destination = ss.copy(text);

  // Delete the temporal sheets in the source Spreadsheet.
  tempSheets.forEach(function(sheet) {ss.deleteSheet(sheet)});

  // Delete the original sheets from the copied Spreadsheet and rename the copied sheets.
  destination.getSheets().forEach(function(sheet) {
    var sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
    if (sheetName.indexOf("_temp") == -1) {
      destination.deleteSheet(sheet);
    } else {
      sheet.setName(sheetName.slice(0, -5));
    }
  });

  // Move file to the destination folder.
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(destination.getId());
  DriveApp.getFolderById(destFolderId).addFile(file);
  file.getParents().next().removeFile(file);
        ui.alert('Your file name is recorded as ' + text + '.');
  }
     if (button == ui.Button.CANCEL) {
    // User clicked "Cancel".
    ui.alert('Operation Cancelled');
  } 
    if (button == ui.Button.CLOSE) {
    // User clicked X in the title bar.
    ui.alert('You closed the dialog.');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the Sheets that you don't want to copy before running the map function. For example if you don't want to include Sheets 1, 3 and 5 you would do it like this:

```js
var sheets = ss.getSheets();

// remove sheet one which is at index 0
sheets.splice(0, 1); 
// remove sheet three which was at index 2 but now the array does not have 
// sheet one so it will be at index 1
sheets.splice(1,1);
// remove sheet 5 which was at index 4 but now it is at index 2 as we removed 2 sheets
sheets.splice(2,1);
var tempSheets = sheets.map(function(sheet) {
// ...
```

#### References

- [Splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)